# Is the converse of this implication correct?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Is the converse of this implication correct?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojOS1.png)

Where $\{A_i : i\in I\}$ is the indexed family of subsets of $Y$ and $A$ is a subset of $Y$.

If the converse of the implication [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojOS1.png) is not always true, then where did I went wrong?
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GleW4.jpg)

Comment: Well the converse is true

Comment: Your proof idea is way too complicated. KISS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \subseteq A$ then indeed for each (fixed) $i$, $$A_i \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \subseteq A \text{ so, in conclusion: } \forall i \in I: A_i \subseteq A$$

and the reverse implication is also true.